# Get Directions between two points in Mapbox?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-android

I recently using mapbox gl on react native instead of Google maps,
I am trying to add a feature that shows a direction from point A to point B on the map.

OR use [Mapbox directions API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/directions/) inside my React Native App

here is my code I tried but after my screen mounted, the app crashed successfully :D

```
import MapboxGL from '@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps';
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';

MapboxGL.setAccessToken(
  '....',
);

class TwoPoints extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.featureCollection = {
      type: 'FeatureCollection',
      features: [
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          id: '9d10456e-bdda-4aa9-9269-04c1667d4552',
          properties: {
            icon: 'example',
          },
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [-73.989, 40.733],
          },
        },
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          id: '9d10456e-bdda-4aa9-9269-04c1667d4552',
          properties: {
            icon: 'airport-15',
          },
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [-74, 40.733],
          },
        },
        {
          type: 'Feature',
          id: '9d10456e-bdda-4aa9-9269-04c1667d4552',
          properties: {
            icon: 'pin',
          },
          geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [-74, 40.733],
          },
        },
      ],
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <MapboxGL.MapView
          ref={c => (this._map = c)}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          style={{flex: 1}}>
          <MapboxGL.ShapeSource shape={this.featureCollection}>
            <MapboxGL.SymbolLayer
              style={{iconColor: 'red'}}
              minZoomLevel={25}
            />
          </MapboxGL.ShapeSource>
        </MapboxGL.MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default TwoPoints;
```

Comment: You could use Mapbox SDK for JavaScript, see the example https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js/blob/master/docs/services.md#getdirections

Comment: @AndrewHarvey But how can handle it with React Native, have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can Import Directions from mapbox-gl-directions like this:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react'
import MapGL from 'react-map-gl'
import Directions from 'react-map-gl-directions'

// Ways to set Mapbox token: https://uber.github.io/react-map-gl/#/Documentation/getting-started/about-mapbox-tokens
const MAPBOX_TOKEN =
  'pk.eyJ1IjoiaGVucmlxdWVub2JyZSIsImEiOiJja3dkZ3c2YmoydzdhMzBvMGRtdWVnd3J2In0.xdCkUviv0yGpX-t8L7ZKQ'

const MapBox = () => {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    latitude: -16.6906,
    longitude: -43.8054,
    zoom: 8
  })
  const mapRef = useRef()
  const handleViewportChange = useCallback(
    (newViewport) => setViewport(newViewport),
    []
  )

  const handleGeocoderViewportChange = useCallback((newViewport) => {
    const geocoderDefaultOverrides = { transitionDuration: 1000 }

    return handleViewportChange({
      ...newViewport,
      ...geocoderDefaultOverrides
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100%' }}>
      <MapGL
        ref={mapRef}
        {...viewport}
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11"
        onViewportChange={handleViewportChange}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
      >
        <Directions
          mapRef={mapRef}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
          position="top-left"
          unit="metric"
          language="pt-BR"
        />
      </MapGL>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MapBox
```